# Exclude custom taxonomy tag from loop

Tags: customization, taxonomy, loop, exclude

I have the following code at the beginning of a loop:

```
<?php query_posts('showposts=3&cat=84'); ?>
<?php $posts = get_posts('category=84&numberposts=3&offset=0'); foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
```

I have a custom taxonomy called "display," with a tag called "featured-slider." In this loop, I want to include everything from category 84, but I want to exclude everything with a "featured-slider" value in the "display" taxonomy.

How would I rewrite the two lines above (query_posts and get_posts) to correctly exclude the custom taxonomy?

thank you

Answer (score 4):

I have rewritten the `query_posts`. As for `get_posts` you are better off using the WP_Query due to more control over the tax_query. [Explained here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/does-get_posts-support-tax_query-rc4).

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'cat' => 84,
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'offset' => 0,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'NOT IN',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'display',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'featured-slider'
        )
    )
);
$wpse42083_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while( $wpse42083_query->have_posts() ) : $wpse42083_query->the_post();
    // write post stuff in here
endwhile;

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Edit: I added the usage.

Comment: +1 for recommending WP_Query over either query_posts or get_posts. @sarah...please review this for the reason why: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts

Comment: Thanks for the help -- but I think I need more help to correctly write the WP_Query version that I would substitute for this line:    <?php $posts = get_posts('category=84&numberposts=3&offset=0'); foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>

Comment: I added the usage in my post.

Comment: Also, `start_wp()` has been deprecated for some time now. It has been effectively replaced by `the_post`.